# Return ternary condition Javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I'm writing a function that should return **Array** when it's true and a **string** when false
I first wrote like this :
`` return (myArr != [])? myArr:`${integer} is prime`; ``
but when myArry is empty, istead of receiving `${integer} is prime` I get an empty arr `[]`,
When I write `` return (myArr.length != [])? myArr:`${integer} is prime ``, it works, and I dont understand why?

below my Code :

```js
function divisors(integer) {
  var i = 2;
  var myArr = [];
  do {
    (integer % i) ? null : myArr.push(i);
    i++
  } while (i < integer);
  
  return (myArr != []) ? myArr : `${integer} is prime`;
}

console.log(divisors(42));
```

Comment: `myArr.length != []` -> `myArr.length != 0`

Comment: `myArr != []` is always true, since an object is never equal to another object.

Comment: Not sure why the `do..while` or even the conditional expression. This seems like the job for a bog standard loop `for (let i = 2; i < integer; i++)` and the body is a simple `if (integer % i === 0) myArr.push(i);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot test an array == [] to see if it is empty  - see comments to your questions

Perhaps you meant this

```js
function divisors(integer) {
  var myArr = Array.from(Array(integer),(x,i)=>i).filter(int => integer%int===0)
  return (myArr.length>1 && myArr[0] === 1) ? myArr : `${integer} is prime`;
}

console.log(divisors(42));
console.log(divisors(11));
console.log(divisors(12));
console.log(divisors(997));
```